# Lightning Component as actionOverride for Standrad NEW Button, do not prepopulate parent record data

Tags: lightning-aura-components, error, platform-bug, lightning-action-override

I'm trying to use `<lightning:recordEditForm>` in a `Lightning Component` as an *`Action Override`* using `lightning:actionOverride` interface.

I've overridden the **Contact New button** with this `Lightning Component`. Issue is, it opens the form, but it won't pre-populate the ***AccountId*** from the source record (as I'm coming from Contact Related List of Account record).

Strange thing that happened was, if I use same code on any other Object (which has a Record Type enabled on it), then I can see in the URL an `additionalParams` parameter with the parent record's ID value.

So for an object without a Record type, when overridding Standard New action, it does not generate any additionalParams parameter with source record id.

Is this a bug?

And do anyone have a way to make the component work and read the source record value, in actionOverride?

My Lightning Component Code (below):

**ContactFormOverride.cmp**

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride">
    <aura:attribute name="disabled" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="saved" type="Boolean" default="false" />
    <aura:attribute name="showSpinner" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

    <div class="slds-card slds-p-around_medium slds-is-relative">
        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSpinner}">
            <lightning:spinner />
        </aura:if>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!!v.saved}">
            Record ID: {!v.recordId}<br/>
            <lightning:recordEditForm   onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
                                        onsubmit="{!c.handleSubmit}"
                                        onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                                        objectApiName="Contact">
                <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
                <lightning:messages />

                <lightning:inputField fieldName="FirstName" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="LastName" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="AccountId" />
                <lightning:inputField fieldName="Birthdate" />
                <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                    <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
                </div>
            </lightning:recordEditForm>
            <aura:set attribute="else">
                <p>Saved! New record id is {!v.recordId}</p>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**ContactFormOverrideController.js**

```
({
    handleLoad: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner', false);
    },
    handleSubmit: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.set('v.disabled', true);
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner', true);
    },
    handleError: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        // errors are handled by lightning:inputField and lightning:messages
        // so this just hides the spinner
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner', false);
    },
    handleSuccess: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var params = event.getParams();
        cmp.set('v.recordId', params.response.id);
        cmp.set('v.showSpinner', false);
        cmp.set('v.saved', true);
    }
})
```

Comment: What you are trying to do - as getting the parent context from a related list on a overridden new button, you can't. Refer to this [**answer**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223772/54851) for details around this behavior.

Comment: damn! I was hoping there is a workaround for this :-|

Comment: Welcome to the group :) Hopefully the idea makes to the product feature list.