# Prepopulate AccountId from contact record in Lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

We have used below lines of code to create contact record from contact related list on account. Is it possible to prepopulate accountId in contact record form?

```
<aura:attribute name="newContact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="simpleNewContact" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="newContactError" type="String"/>

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="contactRecordCreator" 
                  layoutType="FULL"
                  targetRecord="{!v.newContact}"
                  targetFields="{!v.simpleNewContact}"
                  targetError="{!v.newContactError}" />
```

Comment: I am not sure if you can do it using `force:recordData` but you can try `Lightning:RecordEditForm` https://newstechnologystuff.wordpress.com/2018/10/06/lightningrecordeditform-save-data-without-apex/

Comment: You cannot do it as of today. Take a look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/223772/54851), if that helps.

Comment: Why you did not try with force:createrecord event if you are using a full layout. You can set the predefined values there.

Comment: How can i get the accountId,Contactid from overriden New Case Button?