# How can i pass the parameter in URL of Action Button in Salesfoce?

Tags: salesforce-id

I have the scenario, on **Asset** I have related list of **Work Order** and On **Work Order** having related list **Work Order Accessories**.

If I am on Asset, select any Work Order, and trying to add Work Order Accessories, I am not able to get Work Order ID. I am using WorkspaceAPI to get the data, and developing Lighting component for Adding Work Order Accessories.

[image]

[image: sforce]

[image]

[image]

Could anybody help me, how can I get it.

Comment: Where is the button located? On the related list?

Comment: @ShaileshPatil  Yes I have created button in related Object and it is in related List and tried to set data in query parameter like this /lightning/cmp/c__SD_ManageWorkOrderAccessory?workOrderId={!SD_Work_Order__c.Id}, but not setting it up.

Comment: Ok... So getting an ID using a sophisticated standard way is not possible currently(Till last time I used). I am adding a hack way to obtain the parentID from the related list. Adding it in the answer. Please check and see if it fits your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below code. I am not the owner of this code and it is a hack way.

```
    var value = helper.getParameterByName(component , event, 'inContextOfRef');  
/*This method fetch the parent record Id.*/
    getParameterByName: function(component, event, name) {
        name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
        var url = window.location.href;
        var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=1\.([^&#]*)|&|#|$)");
        var results = regex.exec(url);
        if (!results) return null;
        if (!results[2]) return '';
        return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, in Init should I do it?..

Comment: Yes. You can do.

Comment: Bad Luck, not working for me....is it working for you.....

Comment: Yep. Its an old implementation and working fine. Is it possible for you to post the LC code?

Comment: Here it is my init code :doInit : function(component, event, helper, name) {
       debugger;
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");                
        var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params       
        var stateCont =state.ws.split('/');
        var objRecId = stateCont[4];<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>

Comment: If you could help me where I can put this..

Comment: Hi Anita... Could you try the 2nd solution listed here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/223766/lightning-new-case-action-override/244382#244382

Comment: I am signing out of the system. May be tomorrow I can provide you with the solution if the above link didnt help you.

Comment: In state response I am getting this ,{"uid":"1586792012409","ws":"/lightning/r/Asset/02i3K0000005AaeQAE/view"}, but i need which work order clicked to create new Work Order Accessories.I am facing issue there.Poated one more question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61191341/how-to-set-data-in-query-parameter-in-url-of-custom-button-salesforce

Comment: Hi Anita... The solution of the link is working for me. Are you clicking on the button in the related list of the Work Order or Asset?

Comment: On Asset I have related List Work Order and if I select any work order, there I have Work Order Accessories related list, and this button is on Work Order. So, If I am creating directly from Work Order Object, it is working fine. But If I go to Asset, select any work order and then try to create the Work Order Accessory, then I am not getting the work order Id. Here I am facing the issue. I have uploaded one more image where I have selected Asset, then Work order and on that I have Work Order Accessories related List.Here it is getting failed.

Comment: Hi Anita.. You are going correct way. No need to change the code. Could you please check what you are getting in the "addressableContext.attributes.recordId" using console? It should be a Work Order ID even if you get Asset info in the State.

Comment: Hi Shailesh, var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");                
        var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params
        console.log('Page Reference Data'+ JSON.stringify(pageRef));
        console.log('State Data'+ JSON.stringify(state));
        console.log('State Data'+ JSON.stringify(pageRef.state.c__recordId));
        console.log('State Data'+ JSON.stringify(pageRef.state.recordId)); tried this way record id is coming undefined. <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />

Comment: var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
        var state = pageRef.state; // state holds any query params
        var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef;
        console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^State^^^^^^^^^^"+JSON.stringify(state));
        if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
            base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
        }
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));
        console.log("^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^"+addressableContext.attributes.recordId);

Comment: Paste above code in the init method and see what you get in ^^^ log.

Comment: I have tried yesterday,  var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef; this is coming as undefined for me....don't know what is wrong that I am doing.

Comment: Ok... Have you added lightning:isUrlAddressable interface in your LC code? <aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction,lightning:actionOverride, lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" >

Comment: I am able to do with passing parameter in irl with "c__", which I was missing /lightning/cmp/c__SD_ManageWorkOrderAccessory?c__workOrderId={!SD_Work_Order__c.Id}, it is working now. Thanks Shailesh for the help.

Comment: Welcome! Glad it worked! :)